# The "there are suggested edits|flagged posts" indicator refuses to go away

Tags: bug, 10k-tools, suggested-edits

If you have the reputation to review suggested edits, you know that the number of edits is often (read: usually) incorrect. Well, now it's not only incorrect, it also refuses to go away.
[image: Screencap of the top of my screen, with the orange box indicating a suggested edit]

I've clicked on that thing 20 ways from Sunday, but I just cannot get it to disappear. (Note that there were never any edits for me to review.)

**Edit, almost two years later**

This is still happening, except it's more, uh, reliable (can a bug be more reliable?) with the "we have posts flagged for moderator attention" indicator. To reproduce, click on the indicator, review the flags (if any), and wait. Note that the flags do not "go away" when you deal with them - you have to refresh the page somehow to remove anything from the list. But when you refresh the page, the indicator doesn't refresh.

Comment: What happens when you refresh your browser page?  (If that doesn't fix the problem, then the data probably doesn't get updated in real-time).

Comment: On Friday (when this problem occurred), no amount of refreshing the page helped. Neither did closing and reopening the browser, for that matter. However, sometime over the weekend the problem has resolved itself, as in I no longer see that zombiefied pending-edits indicator.

Comment: It is something you can notice for some days, then it vanishes all in a sudden. I understood that number is cached, but I am not clear how much time passes before that cache is cleared.

Comment: Are you still seeing this issue?

Comment: @JarrodDixon, I haven't noticed it lately, but I haven't been visiting the site as often as I used to.

Comment: @JarrodDixon, it just happened again, except with the flag review queue. I've now waited about 5 minutes after handling a flag, and the indicator is still there.

Comment: ...in fact, it's now 10 hours later and the spurious indicator is *still* there.

Comment: And yet another sticky indicator... Does this not happen to anyone else? What is supposed to happen when you click a button on the flag review screen?

Comment: Huh. I'm seeing a slightly different behavior today: after dealing with the flags, they're staying on the page, but greyed out, and they have a red label saying "you have already flagged these" (or something to that effect). Refreshing the flag page (which used to clear the list) has no effect. The indicator still refuses to go away, too.

Comment: ... except now that I opened the site in a new tab while I was writing my comment here, both the indicator and the flag page "fixed themselves". Something is screwy here, but I have no idea what.

Comment: *stops unscrewing @Marthaª's computer* Whoops! Time to scram!

Comment: Good lord: the sticky indicator and ghostly already-handled flags persist across *different computers*!

Comment: They're Zombies. They want brains. Our brains. I'm not going anywhere close to editing anything until there's a skip option that kills the indicator.